# Reducing a list size and checking if the last two inputs are equal

Tags: netlogo

I would like each turtle to have a list of its previous colors. Then I would like to have the list reduced to the last two inputs and check if the two inputs are equal.

In the go section i have inserted:

```
set colormemory lput color colormemory
```

I want my list to be only [ x, y ] and then check if x = y.

How should I proceed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to check if the color memory has atleast 2 elements in the list, then you extract the last two elements via the last and but-last functions.
 Then you check if they're equal by getting the first and second item from the sublist.

If your list was [1 2 3], but last will give you a list of [1 2] and last of the but-last list will give you 2...I sentence the second to last element and the last element together to get your last two elements

```
ask turtles
[
    if length colormemory > 1 [
       let last-two sentence (last (but-last colormemory)) (last colormemory)
       if (item 0 last-two) = (item 1 last-two) [ show "they're equal"]
    ]

]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 
I have few questions about your code. 
Q1
----
How can i shorten the memory? Now when i ask a turtle to show me her memory i obtain:

'ask turtle 11 [ show colormemory]
(turtle 11): [11 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55]'

Could it be possible to reduce the memory to the last 4 (in chronological terms) inputs in the memory? e.g. '[55 55 55 55]'


Again, thank you very much.

Comment: You may want to use sublist: set colormemory sublist colormemory ((length colormemory) - 5) ( (length colormemory) - 1). You'd need to check if the length of the list has atleast 4 elements though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have implemented the code, but it shorten the list to its first 4 elements in the memory, which conflicts with the code of your previous message. When I:  'ask turtle x [ show colormemory] (turtle 11): [11 22  33 44 55 66 77 88]' I obtain [11 22 33 44], while I need the last four entries [55 66 77 88]. I tried reversing the list, but I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you add to the front or back? Something must be off with your other code. This is some example input and output. 

observer> show sublist (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) ((length (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) - 4) ( (length (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)))
observer: [7 8 9 10]

Comment: I was adding them at the back: 'set colormemory lput color colormemory'. I changed the script with 'fput' and changed the rest of the code like this ' to-report color-change
     if length colormemory > 1 [
       let last-two sentence (first (but-first colormemory)) (first colormemory)
       ifelse (item 0 last-two) = (item 1 last-two) [report "they're equal"] [report "they're unequal"]
    ]
end' ----- It seems to be working. Am I missing something? Thank you!